# Correct command no result. 0 row(s) affected Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

Tags: mysql, lookup-tables

I want to add data to a lookup table

locations_borrowers (id_location_borrower (PK), id_borrower (FK), id_location (FK))
from 3 different tables:

- borrowers (id_borrower (PK), forename, surname)
- locations (id_location (PK), street, town)
- all_proto (borrower_forename, borrower_surname, street, town, occupation, telephone)

I wrote the following:

```
 INSERT INTO schema.locations_borrowers (id_borrower, id_location)
 SELECT borrowers.id_borrower, locations.id_location FROM borrowers JOIN schema.all_proto
 ON borrowers.forename = all_proto.borrower_forename AND borrowers.surname = all_proto.borrower_surname 
 INNER JOIN locations ON locations.street = all_proto.street AND locations.town = all_proto.town;
```

The command runs but no results back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run the SELECT and check that return ROWS?

edit:

in my opinion is wrong the database schema.

table all_proto need to have id_borrower and not repeat borrower_forname end borrower_surname.
in the same way if you create the table location_borrowers you don't need fields street and town in table all_proto. if you wont a relation i prefer add id_location in all_proto.

so  I would create

table all_proto(id_borrower,occupation,telephone,id_location)

so your select will be

```
select id_borrowers,id_location from all_proto
```

I hope to be as helpful
bye

Comment: Sorry, yes that helps. I only now read the whole post! The thing is that the all_proto is my original database-the one they gave me and from which I am trying to create new tables with proper relations..So your opinion is to try to add id_location to all_proto and then to derive all I need from there?

Comment: yes but it depends on the relations between the tables you want.
if you know that in the future any borrower can have multiple locations so you better make the table of many to many relationship and putting id_borrower id_locations